# Unable to restore snapshot from URL repository with basic authentication

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk, elasticsearch-6.5

### Problem:

I'm trying to create snapshot on ES instance *ES1*, and restore to another instance *ES2*. It fails to restore when the remote URL requires *basic authentication*.

ES version: 6.5.4

### Success and failure cases:

Success case: When the website exposing the *ES1* repository folder is open to the internet (no authentication), the listing/restore works fine. For example when the repo URL is "http://snapshots.example-server.com"

Failure case: When I add basic authentication to the same URL, it doesn't work. For example when the repo URL is: "http://**username:password**@snapshots.example-server.com"

When I try to list snapshots in the URL repository with basic authentication, the error I get is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "repository_exception",
        "reason": "[remote-repo] could not read repository data from index blob"
      }
    ],
    "type": "repository_exception",
    "reason": "[remote-repo] could not read repository data from index blob",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "i_o_exception",
      "reason": "Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://username:password@snapshots.example-server.com/index.latest"
    }
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

### The Setup:

**Setting up *ES1*:**

Step 1: Modify config file:

```
path.repo: ["/path/to/es1_repo"]
```

Step 2: Creating the repo:

```
PUT /_snapshot/es1_repo
{
  "type": "fs",
  "settings": {
    "location": "/path/to/es1_repo"
  }
}
```

Step 3: Making the repository path accessible from internet:
I have setup an nginx server on the *ES1* machine, to expose `"/path/to/es1_repo”` directory listing, let's say at: http://snapshots.example-server.com. It has basic authentication enabled. You could, for example, access the repo as http://username:password@snapshots.example-server.com and you would see the directory listing.

Step 4: Create the snapshot:

```
PUT /_snapshot/es1_repo/snapshot_1?wait_for_completion=true
{
  "indices": "the_index_name",
  "ignore_unavailable": true,
  "include_global_state": false
}
```

**Setting up *ES2*:**

Step 5: Add to elastic config:

```
repositories.url.allowed_urls: "http://username:password@snapshots.example-server.com"
```

Step 6: Register repo

```
PUT _snapshot/remote-repo
{
   "type": "url",
   "settings": {
       "url": "http://username:password@snapshots.example-server.com"
   }
}
```

Step 7: Check if the snapshot is accessible:

```
GET _snapshot/remote-repo/_all
```

At this step the error pasted at the top appears. If I disable basic authentication, it works fine.

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

You should make these:

1. Add to whitelist the repository in elasticsearch.yaml or docker environment

```
repositories.url.allowed_urls: "http://snapshots.example-server.com"
```

2. Create the snapshots repository

```
PUT _snapshot/remote-repo
{
   "type": "url",
   "settings": {
       "url": "http://snapshots.example-server.com",
       "client": "your_client",
   }
}
```

3. Add username and password to the Elasticsearch keystore

```
    bin/elasticsearch-keystore add url.client.your_client.username
    bin/elasticsearch-keystore add url.client.your_client.password
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up using an `repository-s3` plugin to get the job done at that point. I'll try to give your solution a try when I get a chance.